# React Axios getting reauthorized with JWT token authentication

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I am trying to make a post request using Axios in React but I am getting an unauthorized error:

I have an API called:

```
12.0.0.1:8000/api
```

And I am trying to make a post request using Axios for that I am using this code:

```
  authenticate(signInForm)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.token);
      let token = res.data.token;
      console.log(token);

      // $.ajax()

      axios.post(
        'http://12.0.0.1:8000/api/',
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : `JWT ${token}`
          },
        },
        {
          question_name: 'I am the the first question',
          user_id: '1',
          session_id: '1',
          data: {
            hello: ['armani', 'gucci'],
          },
          created: '2019-12-17T10:56:29.332637Z',
        },
      );
    })
    .catch(err => {
      alert('failed to login');
    });
```

In this code, I can get the exact token when I am pasting that token like this:

```
'Authorization' : `JWT <token>`
```

My code is working I don't know what is the issue I tried saving it into local storage used time interval. In postman same query works fine. But here I am not getting any success.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this, inside the `headers` object, works for you:

```
'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`
```

Comment: The try using like this `Bearer JWT ${token}`

Comment: It is not working is there any way I can log header

Comment: Go to the Chrome Dev Tools and then in the Network tab. All the API calls will be listed there.